# Using the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution function to find specific molecule speeds?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, velocity

I've been looking for problems to practice on this topic and found a problem asking to use the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution function to calculate the fraction of Argon gas molecules with a speed of 305 m/s at 500 K. I thought the distribution function could only be used to find the fraction of molecules moving between two given speeds not at a specific speed. Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: You're right. The question expects you to find the fraction of molecules with speeds between $v$ and $v+dv$ (in terms of $dv$; there will be a factor of $dv$ in the answer).

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can calculate the fraction for molecules with exactly 305 m/s speed. Statistical calculations have an inherent assumption about the 'precision'. Exact 305 m/s speed implies your precision for calculation of speeds has become infinite. You can only determine speeds upto some precision and hence there will be a 'dv' factor in your final answer.